# EF Core migration taking old migrations changes along with new columns

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

**I have added 2 more columns in aspnetusers table and added migrations. But it's failing and showing error stating FK_Projects_AspNetUsers_UserId' is not a constraint.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.**

```
public string NavbarBackGroundImagePath { get; set; }
public string NavbarBackGroundColorCode { get; set; }
```

Added these 2 columns.

```
migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Projects_AspNetUsers_UserId",
            table: "Projects");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_Projects_UserId",
            table: "Projects");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "UserId",
            table: "Projects");

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "WorkspaceId",
            table: "Projects",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: 0);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "NavbarBackGroundColorCode",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            maxLength: 10,
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "NavbarBackGroundImagePath",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            maxLength: 200,
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Projects_WorkspaceId",
            table: "Projects",
            column: "WorkspaceId");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Projects_Workspaces_WorkspaceId",
            table: "Projects",
            column: "WorkspaceId",
            principalTable: "Workspaces",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

But in migration file it's taking all these things.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it seems that this error happens when you want to drop the foreign key constraint in the Projects table, if the Projects table doesn't contain the "FK_Projects_AspNetUsers_UserId" constraint or doesn't contain the "UserId" property, it will show this error.

So, please check the Projects table in the database, whether you have removed the UerId column. And whether the Projects table have the foreign key constraint with the AspNetUsers table. If the Projects table doesn't contain this constraint, try to remove the DropForeignKey related code:

```
   migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Projects_AspNetUsers_UserId",
        table: "Projects");
```